# Batch: Get path to .exe and set as registry entry

Tags: batch-file, registry

I have a batch file searching for an .exe and save it to Log.txt.
Now I want that path to go into a Registry entry (a custom entry) so that my SFX can automatically copy to that path and overwrite the files.
The reason for this is that every user might have a different path to that specific .exe, but I don't want the user to be prompted to enter the SFX extract folder themselves.
Any advice thanx.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too broad. Please [edit] it and provide a code snippet from your _batch file searching for an .exe and save it to Log.txt_ as well as an example of expected registry entry for a particular user.

Answer (score 0):

Alright this is what I have.

```
@Echo off
SET LOGFILE=Log.txt
call :Logit >> %LOGFILE% 
exit

:Logit
dir /s /b E:\dxhr.exe
```

But the output to the Log.txt is "E:\Games\Deus Ex Human Revolution\dxhr.exe"
But it would be nice if I could bypass the whole Log.txt thing and jus save the path to "dxhr.exe" into the registry, WITHOUT the dxhr.exe. So lets say I want to search for dxhr.exe and then I want the output to be just "E:\Games\Deus Ex Human Revolution", and that is what I want to add to a registry value.

Comment: Sorry I am new to stack overflow, and I don't know how to make a code block